# How can I set JSON value to my list

Tags: android, json, fragment

My purpose is to have `autoCompleteText` to get value from the server in JSON format and my textbox send request one second after type character then show my JSON value and this autoCompleteText is in Fragment.

In this code:

```
  List<ProductGetSet> new_suggestions = null;
                                    try {
                    new_suggestions = jp.getParseJsonWCF(constraint.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
```

new_suggestions doesn't get value of String and straight goes to catch then my List doesn't get value but constraint have value

**SearchAdapter.java**

```
public class SearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private Timer searchTimer;
private List<String> suggestions;
public SearchAdapter(Activity context, String nameFilter) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
   suggestions = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return suggestions.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return suggestions.get(position);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    final Filter myFilter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(final CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            final JsonParseProduct jp=new JsonParseProduct();
            if (constraint != null) {
                // A class that queries a web API, parses the data and
                // returns an ArrayList<GoEuroGetSet>

                searchTimer = new Timer();
                searchTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            searchTimer.cancel();
                            searchTimer = null;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("tmessages", e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }, 200, 300);

                List<ProductGetSet> new_suggestions = null;
                                    try {
                    new_suggestions = jp.getParseJsonWCF(constraint.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                suggestions.clear();
                for (int i=0;i<new_suggestions.size();i++) {
                    suggestions.add(new_suggestions.get(i).getName());
                }

                // Now assign the values and count to the FilterResults
                // object
                filterResults.values = suggestions;
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
}

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results != null && results.count > 1  ) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
    return myFilter;
        }
    }
```

**JsonParseProduct.java**

```
public class JsonParseProduct {

public List<ProductGetSet> getParseJsonWCF(String sName) throws IOException {
    List<ProductGetSet> ListData = new ArrayList<ProductGetSet>();
    try {
        String temp = sName.replace("", "20%");
        URL js = new URL("http://webheavens.com/suggestion.php?name="+temp);
        URLConnection jc = js.openConnection();

        InputStream jStream = jc.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(jStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(line);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("results");
        for (int i=0; i < jsonArray.length();i++){

            JSONObject r = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            ListData.add(new ProductGetSet(r.getString("id"),r.getString("name")));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

return ListData;
    }
}
```

**ProductFragment .java**

```
public static ProductFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
    ProductFragment fragment = new ProductFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page);
    args.putString("someTitle", title);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
        title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false);
    acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);

    this.mView = view;

    acTextView.setAdapter(new SearchAdapter(getActivity(), acTextView.getText().toString()));

    acTextView.addTextChangedListener(
            new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    new SearchAdapter(getActivity(), acTextView.getText().toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                private Timer timer = new Timer();
                private final long DELAY = 1000; // milliseconds

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(
                            new TimerTask() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    // you will probably need to use runOnUiThread(Runnable action) for some specific actions
                                }
                            },
                            DELAY
                    );
                }
            }
    );
    acTextView.setAdapter(new SearchAdapter(getActivity(), acTextView.getText().toString()));
    return view;
}
```

I really get confused help me please.

Comment: Please show the stack trace.

Comment: Can you post your json data?

Comment: this line code in JsonParse is url of my json  'URL js = new URL("http://webheavens.com/suggestion.php?name="+temp);'

Comment: I think you meant. `sName.replace(" ", "%20");`... yes?

Comment: Also, this seems to have a NetworkOnMainThreadException.